# Como ler uma linha em C

Tags: c, scanf

Como ler uma linha de inteiros e armazenar em um vetor de tamanho dinâmico ?

Atualmente leio a linha como string(apesar da entrada ser apenas de inteiros) usando gets, única forma que deu certo.

O código está assim:

```
    type def struct{char entradas[50];} Processo 

    int main(){[...] Processo processos; gets(processo[i].entradas); }
```

E funciona, só que eu preciso que seja variável este tamanho de entradas[]

Answer (score 2):

Poderia muito bem continuar com o que está fazendo e criar um vetor de um tamanho praticamente ilimitado e.g `entrada[500000];`

Ou criar um buffer e ir carregando os itens parcialmente :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* vetgen(void *vetor,int newsize,int size){
    void *newarr=malloc(newsize);
    memcpy(newarr, vetor,size);
    free(vetor);
    return newarr;
}
int main(){
    int* vetor,i,aux=1;
    vetor=malloc(sizeof(int)*256);
    do{
        scanf("%d ",vetor+i);
        i++;
        if(i%256==0){
            vetor = (int*) vetgen(vetor,i*(aux+1),i*aux);
            aux++;
        }
    }while(!feof(stdin));
}
```

Este código acima é só para dar uma ideia, para ler entradas em C mesmo do `stdin` recomendo usar o `fgets()` e.g `fgets (buffer, 256, stdin);`

Comment: Sem nunca liberar o buffer anterior? Cuidado aí! Recomendaria utilizar o `realloc` nesse caso.

Comment: acabei esquecendo de usar o `free()` obrigado pelo aviso, já corrigi. Prefiro usar o `malloc()` mesmo, não sei por quê mais sempre tive que fazer mais validações com o realloc. (pelas minhas experiências prévias me pareceu ser menos robusto que o `malloc()` + `memcpy()`.

Comment: A vantagem do `realloc` é que ele pode encontrar memória livre que esteja logo depois do buffer e aumentar a alocação sem criar uma nova nem copiar os dados. Vai fazer `malloc`+`memcpy`+`free` apenas se não houver espaço. Sendo assim, será mais eficiente.